# Using setState but re-rendering is not executed?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have this script, attr is hash object to keep application data.

```
const [attr,setAttr] = useState()

const onSetAttr = (data) =>{
    console.log(data);
    var new_attr = attr;
    for (let key in new_attr) {
        if (key in data){
            new_attr[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
    setAttr(new_attr);
    console.log(new_attr);
}
```

It means the `data` and attr_should be marged as hash.

However setAttr works well but component is not re-rendered.

I google around and found this is related with imutable/mutable.

However in this case, how can i re-rendering forcebly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating the same object, so [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) doesn't work properly. You should create a new one:

```js
const [attr,setAttr] = useState()

const onSetAttr = (data) =>{
    var new_attr = {...attr}; // <= object destructuring creates a new object
    for (let key in new_attr) {
        if (key in data){
            new_attr[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
    setAttr(new_attr);
    console.log(new_attr);
}
```